# How to identify the hardware details of a Linux/Mac machine using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hardware

How to identify the hardware details of a Linux/Mac machine using.Net Core.

For windows machines, we can use `System.Management` and WMI Query.

So is there any similar way to identify the hardware details (like RAM ,Processor,Monitor ,CAM etc) of Linux and Mac machines.

For windows, I'm using:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor");
```

Comment: I made a cross platform library: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Hardware.Info

Answer (score 4):

This is a piece of code to write bash linux commends in .net core:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
    public static class ShellHelper
    {
        public static string Bash(this string cmd)
        {
            var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

            var process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/bash",
                    Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

This is an extension method, you use it like this:

```
var output = "ps aux".Bash();
```

---

As for the commends, refer the [Get Linux System and Hardware Details on the Command Line](https://vitux.com/get-linux-system-and-hardware-details-on-the-command-line/) article on VITUX to help you out writing the commends, it lists most of the commends to collect system information on Linux.

---

**For MAC**:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass mc = default(System.Management.ManagementClass);
ManagementObject mo = default(ManagementObject);
mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (var mo in moc) {
        if (mo.Item("IPEnabled") == true) {
              Adapter.Items.Add("MAC " + mo.Item("MacAddress").ToString());
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me in Linux machine. What about MAC machine.P lease share some inputs for identifying the same in MAC.

Comment: Updated for mac as well :)

Answer (score 4):

I have done a workaround to get hardware info as per Platform. For windows I have used old way of system Management classes, for Linux i have used different Bash commands to Get Processor Id, Model,model version,machine id.
Following are some linux commands i am using

```
1. "LinuxModel": "cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name"
2. "LinuxModelVersion": "cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_version"
3. "LinuxProcessorId": "dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID | sed 's/.*: //' | head -n 1"
4. "LinuxFirmwareVersion": "cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version",
5. "LinuxMachineId": "cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id"
```

Waiting for some support in the .net core framework soon

My gihub post address is https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22660

I have also used similar extension method with a bit optimized code for bash command

```
public static string Bash(this string cmd)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            try
            {
                var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = "/bin/bash",
                        Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                    };

                    process.Start();
                    result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    process.WaitForExit(1500);
                    process.Kill();
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You don't need bash to read text files. You can do this instead: `File.ReadAllText("/sys/class/dmi/id/product_name")`

Comment: Thanks For update @Soonts. Doesn't know this prior. Is this mean all command listed above other then the one started from /sys should use cat while the one starts from /sys should use File.ReadAllText(....)

Comment: This applies to commands which read a complete file with `cat`.
I would leave this command in bash: `dmidecode -t processor | grep -E ID | sed 's/.*: //' | head -n 1` It's technically possible to port that one to C# as well, but bash is simpler and good enough for the job.

Comment: Thanks @Soonts I will love to see equivalent C# code for that command. At the moment cat commands are working so i am letting that as it is. but surely move the code to C# if i got all command convertible.

Comment: C# equivalent of `cat` is a single method call, `File.ReadAllText`. If you want to port that `dmidecode` command, it’s more involved: start the process (the binary location is usually `/usr/sbin/dmidecode`), then instead of `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` read output line by line, find the first line containing `"ID"`, then replace whatever `sed` is replacing (not sure what it is, I have limited experience with Linux) and return the value.

Comment: Thanks Kosta. Will do it